Ошибка при интеграции RealmSwift в проект
Пытаюсь добавить в проект БД Realm через cocoapods. Создала файл Podfile через
pod init:
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'diary' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'RealmSwift'
  # Pods for diary

  target 'diaryTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'diaryUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

После этого сделала pod install, у меня создался workspace где есть 2 "раздела"
diary - мой проект и Pods.
При компиляции появляется ошибка:
Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

Также присутствуют ошибки в файле RealmCollectionImpl

Осмелюсь сделать предположение, что проблема с версиями
в моем случае версия Xcode 15.3
версия Swift 5
версия Realm (20.0.0), RealmSwift (20.0.0)
Я первый раз работаю с realm и, к сожалению, не могу найти ошибку. буду благодарна в помощи. Спасибо!

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
